# How to run a function once all the ajax calls have been done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Say I have this function :

```
function testAjax(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET'
  });
}
```

Now I have a number of nodes (I am using D3), I wish to loop through. Each one may or may not have some files associated. To find out if it does I get the url on the chosen node, inspect the returned data, if it has a file/files I add it to the array of files. I then wish to log the file array only after I have gone through each node and inspected it to see if it has files.

Rest of the code is similar to this :

```
var allFiles = [];
nodes.each(function(d) {
      testAjax(d.url)
        .success(function(data) {
          if (data.files) {
            if (data.files.length > 0) {
              for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                allFiles.push(data.files[i])
              }
            }
          }
        })
    })
//Here is where I want to log/use (call a function passing the files array as an argument) the array of files after its been completed.
```

Comment: Is nodes an array?

Comment: @SinanGuclu yeah loop through each element in an array, retrieve the files (if any), then once retrieved, I wish to do something with all these files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create array of promises and use [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to be resolved when full array is resolved

```
var allFiles = [];
var promises = [];

nodes.each(function(d) {
   // reference to promise
   var req=  testAjax(d.url)
        .success(function(data) {
          if (data.files) {
            if (data.files.length > 0) {
              for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                allFiles.push(data.files[i])
              }
            }
          }
        })
    });
   // push to array
   promises.push(req);
});
$.when.apply(null, promises).then(function(){
    // all promises have been resolved here

}).fail(function(){
    alert('Opps ... something went wrong with one of the requests')
})
```

Comment: Nice one, I'll take a look into this, works as needed, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a check in the success callback to see if you have reached the end of the `nodes` array:

```
var allFiles = [];
nodes.each(function(i, d) {
      testAjax(d.url)
        .success(function(data) {
          if (data.files) {
            if (data.files.length > 0) {
              for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                allFiles.push(data.files[i])
              }
            }
          }
          // Check if the length-1 is equal to the index
          if (i == nodes.length-1) doneLooping();
        })
    })
```

`doneLooping()` should be called as the last callback completes.

[Here](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-each-function-examples/) is a useful page on the `.each()` function.

Comment: this doesn't work. I have tried this before and due to testAjax being asynchronous it doesn't wait for that to finish before checking if i == nodes.length -1 :(

Comment: @thatOneGuy,  charlietfls answer looks promising (no pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like

```
var allFiles = [];
var totalNodes = 0,
    totalSuccessResponses = 0;
nodes.each(function(d) {
   totalNodes++;
   testAjax(d.url)
       .success(function(data) {
           totalSuccessResponses++;
           if (data.files) {
               if (data.files.length > 0) {
                   for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                       allFiles.push(data.files[i])
                   }
               }
           }
           if(totalNodes == totalSuccessResponses) {
               // callback function() 
               // is excuted after all success responses received
           }
       })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/), to be sure all promises have been resolved before perform any treatment.

Here is an example (not directly related to you code, but using mocked calls):

```js
var test = function (i) {
    var result = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i + ": done");
        result.resolve(i);
    }, 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000));
    return result;
};

// with apply to allow the possible usage of $.map on an array of objects, and $.then on each promises
$.when.apply($, [test(1), test(2), test(3)]).done(function (i1, i2, i3) {
    console.log(i1 + " " + i2 + " " + i3 + " are done");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to perform post treatment on you ajax call results before invoking when you can combine the above approach with [$.then](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) and [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)